# How to setEntity in volley?

Tags: android-volley

In httpPost we use setEntity(new StringEntity). But I'm using volley right now. I'd like to use that setEntity method in volley. How can I do that?

I am trying doing below code:

```
    ShZgApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                                Request.Method.POST,
                                Param.baseURL+"oauth",
                                null,
                                new LoginJSONResponseListener(this),
                                new LoginJSONResponseErrorListener(this)){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("grant_type", "password");
            params.put("client_id", "shng");
            params.put("client_secret", "pass");
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }
    };
    ShZgApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

But this gives error:

"09-17 13:50:01.790: E/Volley(28540): [12] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http:/url/oauth"

Please help me.

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374716/server-returned-http-response-code-500-for-url

Comment: Using HttpPost method, connection established and receive proper json response but in volley i am unable to do so.

Comment: can you tell me why do you want to use `setEntity` because i think you can use what you want with the json object

Comment: Did you find decision to the problem?

Comment: @mmlooloo how do you do that? setting Entity via json object

Comment: @Manny264 you can override `getParams` to set your parameter and for http header you can use `getHeaders()`.

Comment: im sending an entity with json data to Firebase Cloud Messaging URL and it has no key just the value (json object) is that also possible seeing as all these methods need a map with a key value pair? @mmlooloo